# Python - how to split a string using regex but preserving pattern that contains the split separator?

Tags: python, regex

Starting from `"param1=1-param2=1.e-01-param3=A"`, how to get

`["param1=1", "param2=1.e-01", "param3=A"]` ? The problem is that the separator "-" may be contained in the value of a parameter.

Franck

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split("-", "param1=1-param2=1.e-01-param3=A")
['param1=1', 'param2=1.e', '01', 'param3=A']
>>> re.split("[^e]-[^0]", "param1=1-param2=1.e-01-param3=A")
['param1=', 'aram2=1.e-0', 'aram3=A']
>>> re.split("[?^e]-[?^0]", "param1=1-param2=1.e-01-param3=A")
['param1=1-param2=1.', '1-param3=A']
```

**EDIT**

OK, I forgot to mention param1, param2, param3 do actually not share the same `"param"` string. What about if we have to split `"p=1-q=1.e-01-r=A"`into the same kind of list `["p=1", "q=1.e-01", "r=A"]` ?

**EDIT**

```
>>> re.split("(?:-)(?=[a-z]+)", "p=1-q=1.e-01-r=A")
['p=1', 'q=1.e-01', 'r=A']
```

Does the job for me as I know parameter names can not carry any `-`.

Thanks, guys !

Answer (score 2):

By using non-capturing group and positive lookahead, capture `'-'` only if it is followed by `'param'`:

```
import re

string = "param1=1-param2=1.e-01-param3=A"
print(re.split(r"(?:-)(?=param)", string))
# ['param1=1', 'param2=1.e-01', 'param3=A']
```

[Live demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/znAIyg/1)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about non-capturing group and positive lookahead: still need to read on these notions. Could you detail a bit further the meaning of both (?:-) and (?=param) in this case ?

Comment: `(?:-)` will make sure the `-` isn't actually captured (otherwise the returned list would be `['param1=1', '-',  'param2=1.e-01', '-', 'param3=A']`, and `(?=param)` will make sure to only capture `'-'` that have `param` after them (so `-` in a middle of a param value will not match)

Answer (score 0):

For other strings,

Try out this https://regex101.com/r/zwI2Mk/1 and https://regex101.com/r/zwI2Mk/1/codegen?language=python

Comment: This will fail if a value is string that contains `-`